# inputTextarea isn't firing the event onchange

Tags: visualforce-component

My inputTextarea with richText enabled isn't firing events. However, if the richText is disabled the event works.

```
<apex:inputTextarea onchange="change()" richText="true" value="{!content}"/>

<script>
                function change() {
                    console.log('changed');
                }
</script>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure there is no scripting error on the page? what do you see in browser console when you load the page or change the content

Comment: No errors in browser console. When I change the content of the inputTextarea, nothing happens. However, if the richText is disabled the event works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <apex:inputTextarea onchange="change()" richText="true"/>
    <script>
       for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {console.log('changed');});
        }
   </script>
```

[Problem solved here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000BgTlQAK)